# Algorithm to generate a biased random bit

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics

You find a fair coin in your pocket: This coin comes up heads (H) with probability 1/2 and tails (T) with probability 1/2. Show that this coin can be used to generate a biased random bit.Consider the following recursive algorithm GetBiasedBit, which does not take any input:

```
Algorithm GetBiasedBit:
  //all coin flips made are mutually independent flip the coin;
if the result is H
  then return 0
else b = GetBiasedBit
return 1 − b
endif
```

The sample space S is the set of all sequences of coin flips that can occur when running algorithm GetBiasedBit. Determine this sample space S.Prove that algorithm GetBiasedBit returns 0 with probability 2/3.
I can't figure out how to determine sample space in this case. Any hints will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To find the sample space, imagine you modify the program so that it prints the result of any coin flip it makes. Notice that the program stops if it encounters H, and repeats itself if it encounters T.

Let $x$ be the probability that the program returns $1$. (This is less confusing than the other way around. It may be helpful to replace the bits 0 and 1 with A and B.)

Each time we go through the body of the routine, there is a chance of $\tfrac12$ that it returns $0$, and a chance of $\tfrac12$ that it returns $1-x$ (because it calls itself). Therefore,$$x=\tfrac12\cdot0+\tfrac12(1-x)$$